# How do I match [ in a Smalltalk regular expression?

Tags: regex, smalltalk, pharo

I want to match `[` in a regular expression in Pharo 6.

This works fine:

```
| matcher |
matcher := RxMatcher forString: '\['.
matcher matches: '['. "produces true"
```

However, I can't see how to do this inside a `[]`. Neither `[[]` nor `[\[]` work.

I can match closing `]` fine with `[]]`, but I can't work out how to do this with `[`.

Comment: have you tried this? `[\[]`

Comment: @JBone he said, *... Neither `[[]` nor `[\[]` work*.

Comment: ha .. I missed that. thanks for pointing it out @lurker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unsupported

Looking at the implementation of `RxParser>>atom` and `RxParser>>characterSet`, escaping characters in the range set is simply not supported.

According to the documentation, other "special" characters (^,-,]) can be handled only by a specific placement within the set so not to trigger parsing of a different branch.

### Workaround

A workaround would be to split the range set into or-ed group, e.g.

```
[[a-z]
```

into

```
(\[|[a-z])
```

### Better Tool

Note that Pharo users are typically directed to use PetitParser instead of regular expressions for text parsing, as PetitParser is easier to manage and debug. A sort of more object-oriented take on regular expressions to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

*I am adding a GNU Smalltalk related answer because the question is tagged with [smalltalk] and therefore likely to turn up in internet search results.*

In GNU Smalltalk, [regexs  have Perl like synta](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/gst.html#Regular-expressions)x, and the character `[` can be escaped as `\[`. For example:

```
st> '[ac' =~ '\[[ab]' 
MatchingRegexResults:'[a'
st> '[bc' =~ '\[[ab]' 
MatchingRegexResults:'[b'
```

Escaping works within a range as well:

```
st> '[bc' =~ '[\[b]' 
MatchingRegexResults:'['
```

Which probably makes it worth while to mention that the message `=~` can be passed to a string along with a regex.

Comment: Your pattern isn't equivalent AFAICS. I'm trying to match `[` inside a range, whereas that pattern is looking for a `[` unconditionally.

Comment: @WilfredHughes I've edited my post to clarify that escaping works within a range as well.